# Error message not show even form field was invalid in angular 6 template driven form validation

Tags: angular, angular6

I tried to show error message in template driven form angular6. But it's not show anymore.I don't know what is wrong with my code
i also

> import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

in main.module.ts, this main module imported in app.module.ts

## HTML file

```
<div class="login-register-form">
     <form name="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && authenticate(f)" novalidate>
     <input type="text" #mobile="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" [pattern]="mobRegEx" required>
     <span *ngIf="mobile.errors?.required && mobile.touched" class="text-danger">Please enter mobile number</span>
     <input type="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="user-password" placeholder="Password" minlength="4" required>
   <div class="button-box">
   <div class="login-toggle-btn">
   <button type="submit"><span>Login</span></button>
   <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
   </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

## ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { User } from "./../../../shared/services/user.model";
import { UserService } from "./../../../shared/services/user.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'suriyaApp-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
user = new User();

  mobRegEx = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$/;
  emailRegEx = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  authenticate(user: User): void{
    console.log(user);
    this.userService.loginAuth(user).subscribe(data=> {
      console.log("hi uu success", data);

    }, error=> {
      console.log("hi uu err", error);

    })
  }
}
```

## user model

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    mobile: string;
    password: string;
}
```

if i bind {{mobile.errors | json}}, then it always shows like {"required": true} even i fill the field.

Comment: Is there any error in browser console or terminal window?

Comment: nope. console showing clear

Comment: add something like this under your form to see if it shows the errors: "{{ mobile.errors | json }}". Should display something like this: { "required": true }

Comment: yes correct. it's showing like that

Comment: "Please enter mobile number" is showing up correctly once you "touch" the input field. Click inside it and then anywhere else. Is this your issue?

Comment: yeah right, once i touch the field and focus out then, it will show and hide err msg if enter mobile number

Comment: if you want to show the error at initial level, remove `mobile.touched` from `<span>`'s `*ngIf="mobile.errors?.required && mobile.touched"`. Then, it will show you error, even when it's not touched. So, your ngIf will be `*ngIf="mobile.errors?.required"`

Comment: if  i remove the mobile.touched from <span>'s then it always showing error message even i give valid data as well as after submit the form. So i don't need to show this message initially. once  we touch and focus out or submit form then it need to show. once i give valid mobile number it should be hide

Comment: If you also want to check if your number is valid you should also use `mobile.errors?.pattern`